# Magento2 store table the store_id needs changed from 2 to 0 to be reset

Tags: magento2, query, table

Not sure how it has occurred, but in our store table, the store_id has changed to 2, but should be 0 I believe for admin. What is the query to run to reset it?

We have backups with the correct values, but when uploading the backup, they do not take, and the incorrect value remains.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Magento2 setup:upgrade Undefined index notice](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/312572/magento2-setupupgrade-undefined-index-notice)

Comment: No! That question you reference is also a question asked by us on a separate issue!