# Magento2 setup:upgrade Undefined index notice

Tags: magento2, database, magento2.3.5

Using the latest version of Magent2; 2.3.5 currently. When running the setup:upgrade query, we are hitting the below error:

*Notice: Undefined index: store in /siteurl/public/vendor/magento/framework/Setup/Declaration/Schema/Db/SchemaBuilder.php on line 152*

Looking at the store table, the admin ID has at somepoint changed from 0 to 2. Which is the likely issue. When restoring an old backup of this table, the id of 2 remains.

How is the above error rectified?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

There is a foreign key in one table which leads to another unexisting table. To find where it is, you should access the file: **siteurl/public/vendor/magento/framework/Setup/Declaration/Schema/Db**.

Before the **line 152**, fix the code following this image: https://prnt.sc/sjjvww

Comment: Yes, that was it, thanks.

Comment: Well gee thanks for posting this as a screenshot which has been removed instead of a code fragment which could stay hosted for ever

Comment: the image on prnt.sc was deleted so how can I fix this?

Comment: -1 for screenshot was removed

Comment: add your fix in comment please, screenshot is removed!